# + Operator in String Class

Tags: java, string

This is regarding the difference in the result returned by '+' operator. Result varies for String literal and String Object.

```
String str="ab";
String str1="c";
String str2 = "ab"+"c"; // Line 3
String str3 = "abc";
String str4 = str+str1;  // Line 5

System.out.println(str2==str3);  // True
System.out.println(str2==str4);  // False
```

With the result we can deduce that with literal, already available object from the string pool is returned as in case of line 3 and with string object new object is returned, as in line 5. Why is it so?

Comment: I was comparing referential equality in this case.

Comment: +1, I also wanna know why, although I assume it's because you are assigning literals string 1-4 and doing concatenation in str4 I'm not sure if theres'a another reason.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `+` oprator for `String`s is handled differently depending on the time when the expression can be evaluated.

When the expression can be evaluated at compile time (as in line 3) the compiler will create a `String` containing only the concatenation. Therefore in line 3 only the `String` "abc" will be created and this `String` will be put in the .class file. Therefore `str3` and `str4` will be exactly the same and will be interned.

When using a concatenation that can be evaluated only at runtime (as in line 5) the resulting `String` is a new `String` which must be compared wth `equals()` as it is a new object.

Answer (score 3):

`String str2 = "ab"+"c";` this is evaluated at **compile** time. It goes to the constant  pool, since it's known already to the compiler.

The other can be evaluated at **runtime**, it won't be part of the constant pool.

It's good opportunity to note the difference from the case where you use [String#concat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#concat%28java.lang.String%29), if you do

`String str2 = "ab".concat("c");`

Since String is immutable, a new String is returned from `concat` causing `str` to not be interned. So in this case, `str2 == str3` will be `false`.

Answer (score 0):

I have marked the question as duplicate, but found that similar answer is not posted so thought of giving it a go. Other answers have already pointed out why the answer is false. 
But here is something that shows you when it will be true.

If you call `intern()` on the second string then the result will be `true`.

> Why this works?

To save memory (and speed up testing for equality), Java supports “interning” of Strings. When the `intern()` method is invoked on a String, a lookup is performed on a table of interned Strings. If a String object with the same content is already in the table, a reference to the String in the table is returned. Otherwise, the String is added to the table and a reference to it is returned.

```
String str4 = (str+str1).intern();
```

Explicitly invoking `intern()` returns a reference to the **interned** String.

Answer (score 0):

When you will create str,str1,str2 and str3 it will point to same string pool.Here it will not create string object.
But when you will create String str4 = str+str1.So str4 is evaluated at runtime.So is wont be part of same string pool where all other strings are pointed.So str4 returns false..

Comment: This is not true. For example,  `str == str1` is `false`. They'll be interned iff they are evaluated on compile time and have the same String value.